# php sql data return array

Tags: php, sql, function

I'm doing a project and I want to send data from function which is on the another php file, then I will show that data in a list which should have button view.

This is my data base management file:

```
<?php
class Database{

    private function connect() {
        $link = new mysqli ("localhost", "xx", "xxx", "table");
        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
            print ("Connect failed: %s\n" . mysqli_connect_error ()) ;
            exit ();
        }
        if (! $link->set_charset ( "utf8" )) {
            printf ( "Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error );
        }
        return $link;
    }

    private function disconnect($link)
    {
        $link->close();
    }

       public function getAllRestaurants($id)
{
    $db = $this->connect();
    $results = array();
    if($res = $db->query("select * from restaurants where id='$id'"))
        {
            while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $results[] = $rows;
                }
        }
    else {
        die($db->error);
    }
    $this->disconnect($db);
    return $results;

}
```

and this is my other php file. I want to show data on list in that file:

```
    <?php

    $ID = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;

    if (empty($ID))
        {
            echo("ERR");
        }

    // Use $ID to fetch whatever data you need

include 'php_includes/db_conf.php';
$db = new Database();
$db->getAllRestaurants();
 $restaurants = $db->getAllRestaurants($id);
foreach ($restaurants as $rest) {
    echo 'Name is ' . $rest['name'] . ' and address is ' . $rest['address'] . '<br>';
}


    mysql_close($db_conx);
    ?>'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem ok:  if($res = $db->query("select * from table where='".$id."'")).. Where id? Maybe where id = .$id. ?

Comment: yes you are right this is also wrong. but still couldnt get information to show as buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect the result rows into an array:

```
    public function getAllRestaurants($id)
    {
        $db = $this->connect();
        $results = array();
        if($res = $db->query("select * from restaurants where id='".$id."'"))
            {
                while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $results[] = $rows;
                    }
            }
        else {
            die($db->error);
        }
        $this->disconnect($db);
        return $results;
    }
```

The calling code might look like:

```
$restaurants = $db->getAllRestaurants($id);
foreach ($restaurants as $rest) {
    echo 'Name is ' . $rest['name'] . ' and address is ' . $rest['address'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: thank you. im adding that part but im a litte bit confused about showing as button. how can i use that array on my other file.

Comment: When you call `getAllRestaurants`, loop over the results and display them however you want.

Comment: i got the point but. for example i have city_id name and adress under that table. how can i get name and adress?

Comment: it's just basic array accessing. I've added a simple example to the answer.

Comment: now im facing with
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table where id=''' at line 
problem. and updated my code

Comment: You need to replace `table` with the actual name of your table.

Comment: `table` is a reserved word, you have to quote it with backticks if you want to use it as the actual table name.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving an `$id` that matches rows in the table?

Comment: The name of the function is confusing. It says `getAllRestaurants`, but it only returns the restaurants that match `$id`. Is it supposed to return all or just one?

Comment: This isn't complicated, the query just does what you tell it to do. If you don't want to match a specific ID, take out the `where` clause. I'm trying to give you the benefit of the doubt that you have some basic understanding of this, but it's getting hard.

Comment: it should return with $id function name should be getRestaurant its for specific restaurant

Comment: i know its not complicated but i really forgot sql indentation in php im trying to fix it but got confused and couldnt figure it out. im trying it for 4 hours maybe and im started to think am i an idiot... -_-

Comment: if it's returning an empty array, then there's no matching restaurant for the ID you gave. I can't help you any more than that, you need to check your data.